# Scraping a plain text file with no HTML?

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I have the following data in a plain text file:

```
1.  Value
Location :  Value
Owner:  Value
Architect:  Value

2.  Value
Location :  Value
Owner:  Value
Architect:  Value

... upto 200+ ...
```

The numbering and the word Value changes for each segment.

Now I need to insert this data in to a MySQL database.

Do you have a suggestion on how can I traverse and scrape it so I can get the value of the text beside the number, and the value of "location", "owner", "architect" ?

Seems hard to do with DOM scraping class since there is no HTML tags present.

Comment: A simple while should be good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will work with a very simple stateful line-oriented parser. Every line you cumulate parsed data into an array(). When something tells you're on a new record, you dump what you parsed and proceed again.

Line-oriented parsers have a great property : they require little memory and what's most important, constant memory. They can proceed with gigabytes of data without any sweat. I'm managing a bunch of production servers and there's nothing worse than those scripts slurping whole files into memory (then stuffing arrays with parsed content which requires more than twice the original file size as memory).

This works and is mostly unbreakable :

```
<?php
$in_name = 'in.txt';
$in = fopen($in_name, 'r') or die();

function dump_record($r) {
    print_r($r);
}

$current = array();
while ($line = fgets($in)) {
    /* Skip empty lines (any number of whitespaces is 'empty' */
    if (preg_match('/^\s*$/', $line)) continue;

    /* Search for '123. <value> ' stanzas */
    if (preg_match('/^(\d+)\.\s+(.*)\s*$/', $line, $start)) {
        /* If we already parsed a record, this is the time to dump it */
        if (!empty($current)) dump_record($current);

        /* Let's start the new record */
        $current = array( 'id' => $start[1] );
    }
    else if (preg_match('/^(.*):\s+(.*)\s*/', $line, $keyval)) {
        /* Otherwise parse a plain 'key: value' stanza */
        $current[ $keyval[1] ] = $keyval[2];
    }
    else {
        error_log("parsing error: '$line'");
    }
}

/* Don't forget to dump the last parsed record, situation
 * we only detect at EOF (end of file) */
if (!empty($current)) dump_record($current);

fclose($in);
?>
```

Obvously you'll need something suited to your taste in `function dump_record`, like printing a correctly formated INSERT SQL statement.

Comment: I've edited my comment to stress on the stream/line-oriented parser. The PHP culture is so file()/file_get_contents() oriented, but this does not scale. And you often want to scale, especially on data import problems like this one. Eat your data one record at a time !

Answer (score 5):

If the data is constantly structured, you can use `fscanf` to scan them from file.

```
/* Notice the newlines at the end! */
$format = <<<FORMAT
%d. %s
Location :  %s
Owner:  %s
Arcihtect:  %s


FORMAT;

$file = fopen('file.txt', 'r');
while ($data = fscanf($file, $format)) {
    list($number, $title, $location, $owner, $architect) = $data;
    // Insert the data to database here
}
fclose($file);
```

More about [`fscanf` in docs](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php).

Comment: +1 for the line-oriented parsing, plus many people will prefer the fscanf style rather than the regex stuff I proposed in my own comment. My solution is more robust wrt to whitespacing and report line-level errors, but it's twice the amount of code.

Comment: +1 for `fscanf`.  I didn't know about this function, and it looks really useful.

Comment: How do you make this work if the values have space and other characters? For example `"This, is the (value)!"`.

Comment: If the the values follow a constant structure, just modify the format string accordingly. It can get messy though. If the values vary a lot, I suggest you to use some of the other solutions such as [Topener's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8432336/1076353).

Answer (score 4):

If every block has the same structure, you could do this with the `file()` function: http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

```
$data = file('path/to/file.txt');
```

With this every row is an item in the array, and you could loop through it.

```
for ($i = 0; $i<count($data); $i+=5){
    $valuerow = $data[$i];
    $locationrow = $data[$i+1];
    $ownerrow = $data[$i+2];
    $architectrow = $data[$i+3];
    // strip the data you don't want here, and instert it into the database.
}
```

Comment: Of course inside the for and after the statements should be the sql query to insert the data

Comment: @Aurelio : not necessarily ... I always prefer writing to a tab delim or similar file, and then using the database's bulk load tool (sqlldr, mysql's LOAD DATA INFILE, etc.  It gives you a chance to review the parsing before inserting.

Comment: @Joe Good solution too but Topener doesn't write neither mine nor your solution. With his for, every time the same vars are overwrited. This was the sense of my comment.

Comment: @Aurelio : actually, it doesn't overwrite -- it's an array that's growing oddly, but nothing should be overwritten.  Although, as zerodeux mentions, it's more memory efficient to not build up the array, and dump on each loop iteration (and even better to not slurp in the whole file)

Answer (score 2):

This will give you what you want,

```
$array = explode("\n\n", $txt);
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    $id_pattern = '#'.($key+1).'. (.*?)\n#';
    preg_match($id_pattern, $value, $id);

    $location_pattern = '#Location \: (.*?)\n#';
    preg_match($location_pattern, $value, $location);


    $owner_pattern = '#Owner\: (.*?)\n#';
    preg_match($owner_pattern, $value, $owner);


    $architect_pattern = '#Architect\: (.*?)#';
    preg_match($architect_pattern, $value, $architect);

    $id = $id[1];
    $location = $location[1];
    $owner = $owner[1];
    $architect = $architect[1];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (id, location, owner, architect) VALUES ('".$id."', '".$location."', '".$owner."', '".$architect."')");
//Change MYSQL query

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Topener solution, here's an example if each block is 4 lines + blank line:

```
$data = file('path/to/file.txt');
$id = 0;
$parsedData = array();
foreach ($data as $n => $row) {
  if (($n % 5) == 0) $id = (int) $row[0];
  else {
    $parsedData[$id][$row[0]] = $row[1];
  }
}
```

Structure will be convenient to use, for MySQL or whatelse. I didn't add code to remove the colon from the first segment.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/(\d+)\.(.*?)\sLocation\s*\:\s*(.*?)\sOwner\s*\:\s*(.*?)\sArchitect\s*\:\s*(.*?)\s?/i",$txt,$m);

$matched = array();

foreach($m[1] as $k => $v) {

    $matched[$v] = array(
        "location" => trim($m[2][$v]),
        "owner" => trim($m[3][$v]),
        "architect" => trim($m[4][$v])
    );

}
```